# Getting error when creating access token :- {"error": "invalid_client"}

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0, access-token

I perform below steps to create an access token. but getting error {"error": "invalid_client"}

1. go to this link http://<ip_address>:/o/applications/
2. fill form to register your application
3. enter below command in CMD

curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=<user_name>&password=" -u"<client_id>:<client_secret>" http://<ip_address>:/o/token/

4. Also, I installed required libraries for access token help of this https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html
5. Image of error attached below
   [Error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5XGS.png)

Answer (score 0):

you use hashed client secret now, you must use the clear client secret before you save your new application in the web interface